$x^3 - 9 = 0$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{Z}/31 \mathbb{Z}$. Possible different argument?
I know this question has been asked before and I have seen different aproaches to it. However, I answered in a way that I don't know if it's correct.
First of all I calculated the order of $[9]_{31}$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/31\mathbb{Z})^*$, which is $15$.
Clearly $[0]_{31}$ isn't a solution to the equation, so let us now work in $(\mathbb{Z}/31\mathbb{Z})^*$. If $[m]_{31}$ is a solution to the equation, then $[m]_{31}^3 = [9]_{31}$. So, in $(\mathbb{Z}/31\mathbb{Z})^*$ we have that $|[m]_{31}^3| = |[9]_{31}| = 15$. Then we can conclude that the (multiplicative) order of $[m]_{31}$ has to satisfy the following equation:
$$|[m]_{31}^3| = \frac{\operatorname{lcm}(3,|[m]_{31}|)}{3} \Leftrightarrow \operatorname{lcm}(3,|[m]_{31}|) = 15 \cdot 3 =45$$
Now, the set of the divisors of $45$ is $\{1,3,5,9,15,45 \}$ and we have that $|[m]_{31}| $ belongs to this set. We can immediately exclude $|[m]_{31}| = 1$ and $|[m]_{31}| = 45$. The former because $[1]_{31}$ does not solve the initial equation and the latter because $|(\mathbb{Z}/31\mathbb{Z})^*| = 30 \geq |[m]_{31}|$. We can then see that for all the other possibilities of $|[m]_{31}|$, we have $\operatorname{lcm}(3,|[m]_{31}|) \neq 45$. We conclude that the initial equation has no solutions in $\mathbb{Z}/31 \mathbb{Z}$.
Where I'm having doubts: I believe that I didn't do the passage from $\mathbb{Z}/31 \mathbb{Z}$ to $(\mathbb{Z}/31 \mathbb{Z})^*$ correctly. I feel like I might have done something wrong in the part $[m]_{31}^3 = [9]_{31}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/31 \mathbb{Z}$ implies  $|[m]_{31}^3| = |[9]_{31}|$ in $(\mathbb{Z}/31 \mathbb{Z})^*$.
Thank you.

Your argument is the one used here. If $x^3=9$ in $\Bbb Z/31$, then $x^3=9$ in the group $U(39)$.

@Dietrich in the group $U(31)$.

From How to ask a good question: "Your question should be clear without the title. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

@DinisP. More simply, mod $31$, if $x^3\equiv9$ then $9^{10}\equiv x^{30}\equiv1$, which contradicts $o(9)=15$.

@Anne Bauval. Thank you, I understand it now.

This is an application of Euler's Criterion - see the Remark in the linked dupe.

Alright thank you very much
